# Column is Identity Key but not Database Generated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How do I designate a  column to be the database identity that is unique, but it is not database generated?  Here is how I would do it normally if REPORT_ID is database generated:

```
[Table("[Report.Settings]")]
public partial class Report_Settings
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int INSTANCE_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long REPORT_ID { get; set; }

    public string REPORT_METADATA { get; set; }

    public string REPORT_GRID_SETTINGS { get; set; }

    public virtual Report Report { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you do not want the identity field to be auto generated..?

Comment: There is an [Index attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index) if that's what you mean.

Comment: Isn't that what `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` is for?

Comment: "An Identity column is a column (also known as a field) in a database table that is made up of values generated by the database."  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column.

Comment: Each key field is unique, EF (or DBMS, it depends) will actually create a UNIQUE INDEX on the key column(s) of each table. Your Identity Attribute means that the column should be database generated (that is, automatically incremented from the intern identity table), you should alter it to DatabaseGeneratedOption.None if you actually want to provide the value yourself.